# How can I trim the leading and trailing comma in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string that is like below.

```
,liger, unicorn, snipe,
```

how can I trim the leading and trailing comma in javascript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720264/remove-last-comma-from-a-string/17720342

Answer (score 173, accepted):

because I believe everything can be solved with regex:

```
var str = ",liger, unicorn, snipe,"
var trim = str.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, "")
// trim now equals 'liger, unicorn, snipe'
```

Comment: @eyelidlessness Is there are joke related to your comment? I'm OutOfTheLoop

Comment: For @mohitmun (and anyone else who comes along). 'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.' More info: https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Answer (score 42):

While cobbal's answer is the "best", in my opinion, I want to add one note: Depending on the formatting of your string and purpose of stripping leading and trailing commas, you may also want to watch out for whitespace.

```
var str = ',liger, unicorn, snipe,';
var trim = str.replace(/(^\s*,)|(,\s*$)/g, '');
```

Of course, with this application, the value of using regex over basic string methods is more obvious.

Comment: the whitespace addition was the clincher for me.

Comment: if anybody's interested about trimming spaces also, better use herostwist's answer below, its better.

Answer (score 37):

If you want to make sure you don't have any trailing commas or whitespace, you might want to use this regex.

```
var str = ' , , , foo, bar,    ';
str = str.replace(/(^[,\s]+)|([,\s]+$)/g, '');
```

returns

```
"foo, bar"
```

Comment: For those wondering why this differs from eyelidlessness's, this solution strips spaces that are before the trailing comma or after the opening comma.

Comment: It also handles multiple leading or trailing commas. For example, `,,,liger, unicorn, snipe,,,` -> `liger, unicorn, snipe`.

Comment: It doesn't replace the commas coming after snipe. This is better `str.replace(/^[,\s]+|[,\s]+$/g, '').replace(/,[,\s]*,/g, ',');`

Comment: yes it does @cyonder - [https://jsfiddle.net/hws45zpd/](https://jsfiddle.net/hws45zpd/)

Comment: Well you have moved the goalposts @cyonder, the question was "how can I trim the leading and trailing comma". In order to make your comment valid you have had to invent new problems.

Comment: @herostwist People, who are looking for a regex solution, don't know how to use regex and they basically want the perfect solution! Sometimes they miss testing some conditions, not realizing what their actual problem is. This solution that I provided can be used for 'comma-separated' inputs. Ex; An input field that is waiting for `comma separated city names or tags, etc.` So, in this case you don't want any problem with comma whatsoever. This answer that I provided helps in this way. That's all.

Comment: @cyonder I really like your regex, it matches exactly what I need (with the exception that I added an additional space after comma in the result - it's prettier :))

Answer (score 21):

Try this, since not *everything* can be solved by REs and even some things that can, shouldn't be :-)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str = ",liger, unicorn, snipe,";
    if (str.substr(0,1) == ",") {
        str = str.substring(1);
    }
    var len = str.length;
    if (str.substr(len-1,1) == ",") {
        str = str.substring(0,len-1);
    }
    alert (str);
</script>
```

Comment: Ask not what REs can do for you, but what you can do for REs! :)

Answer (score 11):

In ECMAScript 5 and above, you can now do a one-liner

```
',liger, unicorn, snipe,'.split(',').map(e => e.trim()).filter(e => e).join(', ')
```

Comment: perfect solution