# Remove last comma (and possible whitespaces after the last comma) from the end of a string

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript, how can I remove the last comma,  but only if the comma is the last character or if there is only white space after the comma? This is my code.
I got a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96bEy/). But it has a bug.

```
var str = 'This, is a test.'; 
alert( removeLastComma(str) ); // should remain unchanged

var str = 'This, is a test,'; 
alert( removeLastComma(str) ); // should remove the last comma

var str = 'This is a test,          '; 
alert( removeLastComma(str) ); // should remove the last comma

function removeLastComma(strng){        
    var n=strng.lastIndexOf(",");
    var a=strng.substring(0,n) 
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Should it also remove the spaces at the end?

Comment: if its only blank space, yes

Comment: How about any spaces before the comma in question? Should those be removed too? in which case: str = str.replace(/,\s*$/, ""); would become str = str.replace(/\s*,\s*$/, "");

Answer (score 540, accepted):

This will remove the last comma and any whitespace after it:

```
str = str.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
```

It uses a regular expression:

- The `/` mark the beginning and end of the regular expression
- The `,` matches the comma
- The `\s` means whitespace characters (space, tab, etc) and the `*` means 0 or more
- The `$` at the end signifies the end of the string

Comment: Use str.replace(/,+/g,",").replace(/(,\s*$)|(^,*)/, ""); if you want to remove the initial empty comma or, double comma, example ",,8,,7" would become "8,7"

Comment: @ParkashKumar Jon has already mentioned about the last `/`. `The / mark the beginning and end of the regular expression`.

Answer (score 20):

you can remove last comma from a string by using slice() method, find the below [example](http://www.etechpulse.com/2015/09/remove-last-comma-from-string-using-jquery.html):

```
var strVal = $.trim($('.txtValue').val());
var lastChar = strVal.slice(-1);
if (lastChar == ',') {
    strVal = strVal.slice(0, -1);
}
```

Here is an Example

```js
function myFunction() {
 var strVal = $.trim($('.txtValue').text());
 var lastChar = strVal.slice(-1);
 if (lastChar == ',') { // check last character is string
  strVal = strVal.slice(0, -1); // trim last character
  $("#demo").text(strVal);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p class="txtValue">Striing with Commma,</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 19):

```
function removeLastComma(str) {
   return str.replace(/,(\s+)?$/, '');   
}
```

Comment: \s* is better version of (\s+)?

Answer (score 8):

In case its useful or a better way:

```
str = str.replace(/(\s*,?\s*)*$/, "");
```

It will replace all following combination end of the string:

```
1. ,<no space>
2. ,<spaces> 
3. ,  ,  , ,   ,
4. <spaces>
5. <spaces>,
6. <spaces>,<spaces>
```

Comment: `str = str.replace(/[,\s]*$/, "");` would remove any number of trailing `,` or spaces in any order or combination.

Answer (score 6):

The greatly upvoted answer removes not only the final comma, but also any spaces that follow. But removing those following spaces was *not* what was part of the original problem. So:

```
let str = 'abc,def,ghi, ';
let str2 = str.replace(/,(?=\s*$)/, '');
alert("'" + str2 + "'");
'abc,def,ghi '
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dc8moa3k/

Answer (score 3):

Remove last comma. Working example

```js
function truncateText() {
  var str= document.getElementById('input').value;
  str = str.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
  console.log(str);
}
```

```html
<input id="input" value="address line one,"/>
<button onclick="truncateText()">Truncate</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

First, one should check if the last character is a comma.
If it exists, remove it.

```
if (str.indexOf(',', this.length - ','.length) !== -1) {
    str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
}
```

*NOTE* str.indexOf(',', this.length - ','.length) can be simplified to str.indexOf(',', this.length - 1)

Answer (score 2):

long shot here

```
var sentence="I got,. commas, here,";
var pattern=/,/g;
var currentIndex;
while (pattern.test(sentence)==true)  {    
  currentIndex=pattern.lastIndex;
 }
if(currentIndex==sentence.trim().length)
alert(sentence.substring(0,currentIndex-1));
else
 alert(sentence);
```

Comment: Athough the question has already been answered, I was intrigued by your solution and decided to test. Unfortunately, it does not work :(

Comment: Use this input "This, is a test." Ideally the output should be the same sentence but in  your program it gives it as "This". If i am right then mark my question +1. If im wrong i will mark your solution +1

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/rpss/3rSNr/](http://jsfiddle.net/rpss/3rSNr/)  All the commas' indices are fetched and put into "currentIndex" replacing one after the other in the loop(tesing for matching pattern and fetching the index when a match is found). finally that variable is left with the index of the last comma

Comment: :) true, that code will remove the last comma, but you wanted the last comma _at the end of the sentence_ to be removed, there..there.. your question is marked +1

Comment: Not exactly. You missed this part "but only if the comma is the last character or if there is only white space after the comma"

Answer (score 2):

you can remove last comma:

```
var sentence = "I got,. commas, here,";
sentence = sentence.replace(/(.+),$/, '$1');
console.log(sentence);
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last comma from a string even if there are characters after it (which is different from what has been asked), you need

```js
text.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, '')
text.replace(/,(?![^,]*,)/, '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gOWgHr/1). *Details*:

- `,(?=[^,]*$)` - a comma that is immediately followed with any zero or more chars other than a comma till end of string.
- `,(?![^,]*,)` - a comma that is not immediately followed with any zero or more chars other than a comma and then another comma.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = '1,This is a test, and this is another,  ...';
console.log(text.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, ''));
console.log(text.replace(/,(?![^,]*,)/, ''));
```

Comment: Author asks to remove comma ONLY if it is the last char (plus possible whitespace). Your code removes it even if there are other chars after the comma.

Comment: @gorn Correct, but Google brought me here for "remove the last comma in a string". So, this answer is surely helpful for those users.

Comment: Well, I do not think, that SO wants answers to anything else than what was askes. If you feel its valueable, post it as a separate question :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove whitespace and comma at the end use this,

```
var str = "Hello TecAdmin, ";
str = str.trim().replace(/,(?![^,]*,)/, '')
// Output
"Hello TecAdmin"
```

Comment: isn't /,\s*$/ easier?

Comment: @gorn yes both work

Answer (score 0):

***With or without Regex.***

I suggest two processes and also consider removing space as well. Today I got this problem and I fixed this by writing the below code.

I hope this code will help others.

```js
//With the help of Regex
var str = "        I am in Pakistan, I am in India, I am in Japan,     ";
var newstr = str.replace(/[, ]+$/, "").trim();
console.log(newstr);


//Without Regex
function removeSpaceAndLastComa(str) {
  var newstr = str.trim();
  var tabId = newstr.split(",");
  strAry = [];
  tabId.forEach(function(i, e) {
    if (i != "") {
      strAry.push(i);
    }
  })
  console.log(strAry.join(","));
}

removeSpaceAndLastComa(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting es6, then you can simply do this

```
str = Array.from( str ).splice(0, str.length - 1).join('');
```

- This `Array.from(str)` converts the string to an array (so we can slice it)
- This `splice( 0 , str.length - 1 )` returns an array with the items from the array sequentially except the last item in the array
- This  `join('')` joins the entries in the array to form a string

Then if you want to make sure that a comma actually ends the string before performing the operation, you can do something like this

```
str = str.endsWith(',') ? Array.from(str).splice(0,str.length - 1).join('') : str;
```

Comment: this not taking commas into account, read the original question carefully

Comment: Actually, it does take commas into account. ```var str = 'This, is a test,'; 
str = Array.from( str ).splice(0, str.length - 1).join('');```
This will give you back the string without the ending comma.

Comment: Well, it removes last character in very fancy way (why not use ```str.slice(0, -1)`` instead) and does not work for strings like 'This, is a test,   ' (which should return 'This, is a test')

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you remove the last comma in the string, not the comma if it's the last thing in the string. So you should put an if to check if the last char is ',' and change it if it is.

EDIT: Is it really that confusing?

'This, is a random string'

Your code finds the last comma from the string and stores only 'This, ' because, the last comma is after 'This' not at the end of the string.

Comment: Your answer is more confusing than the question. Sorry for being brutally honest

Comment: xD i get that a lot. Your script finds the last coma in the string and removes everything after it. In that case if the comma is in the middle like in this one 'This, is a test.' the command strng.lastIndexOf(","); will return 4, thus removing everything after the 5th letter. So you have to check if the "," is the last letter of the string before removing the rest :)

Comment: i understand what u mean and i got where i was going wrong. But you answer is more suitable as a comment as it did not help me much. Hope you get what i am saying. No offence

Comment: I was planning to add code too if requested but upon editing in fiddle I saw that there was already a perfect answer so I left it like that. :)