# PegJS - match all characters including ) except if ) is the last character

Tags: javascript, regex, pegjs

I am writing a PegJS grammar to parse SQL statements. I'm working on splitting a function into `function_id(function_args)`. For function args I want to match all characters including `(` and `)` except the last `)`, this being necessary for nested functions.

How do I write a rule to match all characters which includes `)` except when `)` is the last character in the string.

The grammar is given below

```
 Function 
 = func_name open_p args close_p

func_name 
= name:[A-Z]+ {return name.join('');}

open_p
= "("

close_p
= ")"

args
= ar:(.*[^)]) {return ar.join('');}
```

and the test string is

```
AVG(A + AVG(B + C))
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720264/remove-last-comma-from-a-string

Comment: Why not just remove the last character if it is a `)`? `"AVG(A + AVG(B + C))".replace(/\)$/, '')"`

Comment: unfortunately the string cant be manipulated as it part of a larger string being parsed in PegJS. Thus only PegJS manipulations are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules to handle the arguments correctly can help. Also, instead of using `{return name.join('');}` you can use `$()` notation in the rule to combine parsed strings.

`args` can either be `function` or `nonfunction` repeated. `nonfunction` captures everything that is not a function by look ahead.

```
function 
 = func_name open_p (args+ / "") close_p

func_name 
= $([A-Z]+)

open_p
= "("

close_p
= ")"

args
= function / nonfunction

nonfunction
= $((!(function / close_p) .)+)
```