# Remove last comma inside a div in a WordPress page using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm new to JS/jQuery!

I have a plugin who create entries when members submit a form, entries are displayed in a WordPress page.

I want to remove the last comma from div `critselect` in a WordPress page. So, after `CRM` comma must to be removed.

What I'm doing wrong? I'm beginner!

```js
/*This code are in a WordPress page, on top page*/
jQuery(function($) {

  $('.critselect').each(function() {
    var xContents = $(this).contents();
    xContents[xContents.length - 1].nodeValue = "";
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--This code are in a WordPress page -->
<div class="critselect">
  <h4>MY ENTRIES</h4>
  Marketing, Retails / Call center, Office / Back-office / CRM,
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Last Comma from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720264/remove-last-comma-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.critselect').each(function() {
    var xContents = $(this).html();
    var lastCommaPos = xContents.lastIndexOf(',');
    $(this).html(xContents.substring(0, lastCommaPos));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That do the job! As long as I'm beginner you posted the code perfectly formatted.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: How to adapt your code to remove comma on each p (paragraph, row) which is inside div critselect?
Sometimes I have 2 paragraphs inside that div and remove comma only from last paragraph.

Comment: Do you have an example of what that HTML would look like?

Comment: Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/mariusfv/oqvu4hkx/9 with the HTML and your jQuery as a comment.

Comment: Those aren't truly p's though, it's just text with a html break in it, would need a pattern to follow. If each line ending in a comma was wrapped in a <p> tag, that would help.  Do you have any control over the content generation? Is it possible to drop the last comma when creating the content rather than cleaning up later?

Comment: I add a p class to each row: https://jsfiddle.net/mariusfv/oqvu4hkx/13/.
In this way can be accomplished?

Comment: If you can control that, you should find a way to simply not add the comma to the end of the string.

Comment: I can control HTML tags only! I can not control inserted values because are inserted externally by user selection (sometimes they can select 2 values, sometime 5 values, so comma cannot be avoided to last element).

Comment: The BIG problem of last code is: if will not found a comma will remove the entire row!
See, it remove first row if no comma is present: https://jsfiddle.net/mariusfv/trwje8dk/2/
Any solution?

Comment: First check to see if there is a comma, I assumed there always would be.

Comment: Some users select just one department as experience, so in that case there is no comma. Can be solved if is no comma to not remove the entire row?

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('critselect')[0];
var str = div.innerHTML;
var position = str.lastIndexOf(",")+1;

var div.innerHTML = str.substring(0,position - 1) + str.substring(position, str.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there might be whitespace at the end and/or there might not be a trailing comma at all, a regular expression is a good way to go.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.critselect').forEach(el => {
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/,\s*$/, '');
});
```

It's even better if you place the list in its own element. That way you can be certain you're only editing the list, not anything else in the `div.critselect`.

```html
<div class="critselect">
  <h4>MY ENTRIES</h4>
  <span>Marketing, Retails / Call center, Office / Back-office / CRM,</span>
</div>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.critselect > span').forEach(el => {
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/,\s*$/, '');
});
```