# removing the "," comma from the end of a template string

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem is that I can see a small "," comma at the end of each option which I wanted to remove:

```js
HTML = `<select>
${[1, 2, 3].map(e => (`<option>${e}</option>\n`).replace(",", ""))}
</select>`;
console.log(HTML);
```

Comment: Add `.join('')` at the end of your `map()` - As your array is inside of a template literal it will implicitly call `.toString()`, which will join its elements on a comma. So you can remove .replace()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Last Comma from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720264/remove-last-comma-from-a-string)

Comment: And by the way,  I think that using replace in this situation is not a good idea, because the option value itself may have a "," comma, so maybe later I can use the split method and split the last string character which is the ",". But as you may know, I can't use the split method now because it's not a method for the strings

Comment: @DiogoRocha, that linked question isn't a duplicate. Although it might solve that specific issue, the original cause of having commas appearing can be fixed here, instead of the symptoms as proposed in that other question.

Comment: try this after you are done creating your html string. `HTML.replaceAll(',',"")`

Comment: Whatever you choose, add two spaces (or your style) before `<option>` so that the options will be indented inside of `<select>`.

Comment: and if your options are gonna contain comma then better use `HTML.replaceAll(',<','<')` so that you end up removing comma which are preceding the lessthan ( < )character only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLDR

> How about use `join` function like

### Answer

First of all if you console.log `` [1, 2, 3].map(e => (`<option>${e}</option>\n`)) `` you can get this

```js
const this = ["<option>1</option>", "<option>2</option>", "<option>3</option>"]  // Array
```

And if you console.log(`this`) with template literal.
It automatic call `Array.toString()`.

```js
console.log(`${["<option>1</option>", "<option>2</option>", "<option>3</option>"]}`) // automatic call toString()
```

And when you use `replace()` the array must be array and "," is not generated yet

### Example

```js
HTML = `<select>
${[1, 2, 3].map(e => (`<option>${e}</option>\n`)).join("")}
</select>`;
console.log(HTML);
```

Comment: This is the answer, but could you please explain why this comma "," is showing at the end of each option? from where it is coming? is it because of the use of map on the array? or is it because using the backtick string literals?

Comment: @Brad, see `[1,2].toString()`, it gives `1,2`: you're giving an array to be displayed, so `toString` is implicitly called, which adds commas between each item. You need to handle the serialisation of the array yourself, e.g. by using `join` as explained here.

Comment: Oh, I gotta explain it

Answer (score 1):

`.join("")` it

```js
HTML = `<select>
${[1, 2, 3].map(e => (`<option>${e}</option>\n`)).join("")}</select>`;
console.log(HTML);
```