# How can i remove last and first apostrophe ( ' ) from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i remove last and first apostrophe ( ' ) from string.

I have the string is  `"'name'"` and i need to change to `"name"` i don't need the apostrophe symbol (').

Comment: Maybe the `.replace()` method, or the `.slice()` method, or the `.substring()` method, or the `.substr()` method, or... What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO!, please share your code. Have you tried anything. If you are not sure of how to do this, please try googling *how to replace value in string* and try to understand solutions. If then none help you, we will help you

Comment: var firstApostrophe = string.indexOf("'")
var lastApostrophe = string.lastIndexOf("'")
string  = string.slice(firstApostrophe,firstApostrophe+1).slice(lastApostrophe,lastApostrophe+1)

Comment: try this `function replaceat(s,index){
re =s.substr(0, index) + s.substr(index + 1);
return re;
}` and call this function `re1 = replaceat(ur string,string.indexOf('`'));`

`re2 = replaceat(re1,re1.lastIndexOf('`'));`
`console.log(re2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression.

```js
var input = "'Hello Man'";

var output = input.replace(
  /^(?:')(.*)(?:')$/,
  "$1"
);

console.log({output, input});
```

as @nnnnnn suggests, the same result can be achieved in this way:

`input.replace(/^'|'$/g,'')`

Comment: Or `input.replace(/^'(.*)'$/,'$1')` - you don't need the extra groups around the apostrophes. Or just `input.replace(/^'|'$/g,'')`.

Comment: As my professor said, parenthesis are free and should be used to improve readability, `(?:)` indicates a non capturing group and is part of the regex specs. Is just a different way to do the same thing.

Comment: I know what `(?:)` does. My point was that in this case it makes it *harder* to read (or at least, I think it's harder to read) than `/^'(.*)'$/`.

Comment: Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/661317/3783478) and my approach seemed like big overkill, so remove it

Answer (score -1):

This should do it!! [Replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
let e = "'name'";
e.replace(/^'|'$/g,'');
```

PS: Sorry didn't read the question completely !!

Comment: Nope this will not. I'll leave figuring the reason to you

Comment: not any occurrence of `'`, should be removed only `trailing` and `leading`.

Comment: @Rajesh Now I feel like an idiot for not reading the question! :P
Also Hitmands Yup!! Got that. Thanks

Comment: And also you copied the @nnnnnn suggestion without citing him... lol!

Comment: I need to check other comments before giving my own !! Lol :P
Did not see @nnnnnn suggestions until you pointed it out !! Today is not a good day :P

Answer (score -2):

```js
var str = '"\'name\'"';
var cleanStr = str.replace(/"'|'"/g, '"');
console.log(cleanStr);
```

Comment: I think `first` and `last` mean `leading and trailing apostrophe`, the `g`lobal operator will remove any occurrence. Plus, you added `double quotes` to the regex and they doesn't appear in the op.

Comment: I doubt that the input strings actually contain double-quotes.

Comment: I took it as written.  The OP specifically wanted to end up with `"name"`, so that's what s/he got.

Comment: Yes, the example string is `"'name'"` - it could be a stringified JSON key or value, and the OP wants to remove the apostrophes and leave the double quotes.  Let's give him/her the opportunity to clarify instead of making assumptions.