# How can I remove a comma in a list via css?

Tags: css, frontend, web-frontend

```
<div class="post-meta vcard">
    <p>, 
        <a href="http://google.com" rel="tag">Paris</a>, 
        <a href="http://google.com" rel="tag">France</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

As you see, the first row includes a comma, thus the output is ", Paris, France"

How would I get rid of/hide the first comma and space, while also keeping this list centered.  I can only edit via CSS for this.

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvVqoy)

Comment: Edit the file and delete it.

Comment: You can hide/cover it but can't remove/delete it, not with CSS.

Comment: How would I hide/cover?

Comment: Why are you attempting to do it via CSS? Why can't the file be edited in one way or another? See this answer for a Javascript example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/661325/2370075

Comment: Using the pseudo-element, but why'd you even do that?

Answer (score 0):

You literally have two commas here at the end:

```
<div class="post-meta vcard"><p>, 
<a href=" http://google.com " rel="tag">Paris</a>,
```

For centering your list, just use `text-align: center` in your css code.

Comment: I can only control the CSS, so looking for a way to hide the comma via CSS

Comment: Well, in your case, it is probably very hard to do it. Why do you need to remove comma? I mean, what is the effect you want to happen?